# VBA code to filter a big amount of data based on time stamps

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sets of data - one with data points every 10 seconds/minute while the other one has data points every 5 minutes. I need to filter the first data set to only contain the data sets with time stamps ending on 3 or 5 (e.g. 00:13 or 14:58) as this is the same as the other data set.

I have tried some IF functions - no success. I am not sure where to start with a VBA code - my experience with VBA is very very basic.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It really is a massive amount of data and I am not looking forward to doing it manually.

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: formula then filter on the formula would be easiest: `=OR(MOD(MINUTE(A1),10)=3,MOD(MINUTE(A1),10)=5)` to filter on true.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a AND(SECONDE(A1)=0,OR(... to Cor_Blimey solution.